# WSO2 How to set scheduled task?

Tags: ftp, wso2, vfs

Now I have a FTP service. The config like this: http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.1/docs/samples/transport_samples.html#Sample254 . It works every interval time, default is 5 seconds. How to set VFS to a scheduled task or how to expose VFS to a web service? Could you help me? Best regards.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585778/wso2-how-to-set-vfs-to-a-scheduled-task Answered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer Scheduled Tasks User Guide [[1]](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/Adding+and+Scheduling+Tasks). Select the Trigger Type as `Cron` and define it as a `Cron` style entry. To write a task sample [[2]](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/Writing+Tasks+Sample).

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. If is a web service, I can add a task at this way.But my service is a VFS. It works every interval time, default is 5 seconds. How to set VFS to a scheduled task or how to expose VFS to a web service? Could you help me? Best regards. My VFS config like this: http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.1/docs/samples/transport_samples.html#Sample254