# WSO2 How to set VFS to a scheduled task

Tags: wso2, vfs

In wso2, VFS running default 5 minutes. I think this is bad for performance. I want VFS running when server is not busy. For example, maybe at 02:00 no body request, then VFS can work. I tried add scheduled task, but it no use. Anyone can tell me how to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Seems like they don't want to do that (but our customers need it!): https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-886?jql=text%20~%20%22vfs%20cron%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is related to [WSO2 How to set scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526580/wso2-how-to-set-scheduled-task) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537190/how-to-vfs-service-exposed-as-a-web-service questions. Seems you want to do the VFS polling on a particular time of the day (scheduled to a non-peak time) or via a web service. But unfortunately I don't think it's possible to plug a CRON expression or a service call to VFS, because of how VFS transport has been implemented. Anyway you can suggest this as a feature request at [WSO2 JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:roadmap-panel)

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting can lead to starvation. If the ESB server is continuously hit with requests, the VFS task will never run. As mentioned in the [ESB documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB/VFS+Transport) you can adjust the polling interval by specifying the transport.PollInterval parameter. An example of increasing the polling interval to 30 minutes can look like this in the ESB configuration:

```
      <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1800000</parameter>
```

Comment: Your given interval is actually 20 days and 20 hours. As per documentation here (https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/VFS+Transport), you need to append **ms** next to the number for it to be read as milliseconds. Otherwise, it will be read as seconds.